# Laravel: Agregar una condición where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy buscando agregar un **where** más a la condición siguiente:

```
 $propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
    ->where('tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0])
    ->get();
```

Algo similar a:

```
$propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))
    ->where('tipoDePropiedad_id', '=', $tipoPropiedad_id[0])
    ->where('categoria_id', '=', $categoria_id)
    ->get();
```

¿ Alguien conoce como se puede agregar un parámetro más búsqueda ?

Comment: La segunda forma es la indicada, ¿qué error te da?

Comment: Pido disculpas me di cuenta que estaba pasando un string y necesitaba el id. Lo solucione obteniendo el id de la siguiente manera: $categoria_id = Category::where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->pluck('id');

Answer (score 0):

Pido disculpas me di cuenta que estaba pasando un string y necesitaba el id. Lo solucione obteniendo el id de la siguiente manera:

```
$categoria_id = Category::where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->pluck('id');
```